# Will the expectations converge in this case?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume that $0\le a<b$. Assume that you  have a positive Borel-function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$. Assume that you have a sequence of Borel-positive functions $s_n:[a,b]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$, and that $s_n\rightarrow f$ Lebesgue a.e. on $[a,b]$ and also that $\int_{[a,b]}|s_n(x)-f(x)|dx\rightarrow 0$. Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values in $[a,b]$. Do we then have that

$$E\left[s_n(X)\right]\rightarrow E\left[f(X)\right]?$$

Comment: It depends on the relationship between the expectation measure and the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @copper.hat Will it work if we also assume that $X$ is a continuous random variable?

Answer (score 0):

A simple counter-example: Let $s_n(x)=x^{n}$ and $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$ and $X \equiv 1 $.